# Progress bar and multiple threads, decoupling GUI and logic - which design pattern would be the best?

Tags: multithreading, model-view-controller, progress-bar, observer-pattern, decoupling

I'm looking for a design pattern that would fit my application design.

My application processes large amounts of data and produces some graphs. 
Data processing (fetching from files, CPU intensive calculations) and graph operations (drawing, updating) are done in seperate threads.

Graph can be scrolled - in this case new data portions need to be processed.
Because there can be several series on a graph, multiple threads can be spawned (two threads per serie, one for dataset update and one for graph update).

I don't want to create multiple progress bars. Instead, I'd like to have single progress bar that inform about global progress. At the moment I can think of MVC and Observer/Observable, but it's a little bit blurry :) Maybe somebody could point me in a right direction, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I once spent the best part of a week trying to make a smooth, non-hiccupy progress bar over a very complex algorithm.

The algorithm had 6 different steps. Each step had timing characteristics that were seriously dependent on A) the underlying data being processed, not just the "amount" of data but also the "type" of data and B) 2 of the steps scaled extremely well with increasing number of cpus, 2 steps ran in 2 threads and 2 steps were effectively single-threaded.

The mix of data effectively had a much larger impact on execution time of each step than number of cores.

The solution that finally cracked it was really quite simple. I made 6 functions that analyzed the data set and tried to predict the actual run-time of each analysis step. The heuristic in each function analyzed both the data sets under analysis and the number of cpus. Based on run-time data from my own 4 core machine, each function basically returned the number of milliseconds it was expected to take, *on my machine*.

f1(..) + f2(..) + f3(..) + f4(..) + f5(..) + f6(..) = total runtime in milliseconds

Now given this information, you can effectively know what percentage of the total execution time each step is supposed to take. Now if you say step1 is supposed to take 40% of the execution time, you basically need to find out how to emit 40 1% events from that algorithm. Say the for-loop is processing 100,000 items, you could probably do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++){
     if (i % (numItems / percentageOfTotalForThisStep) == 0) emitProgressEvent();
     .. do the actual processing ..
}
```

This algorithm gave us a silky smooth progress bar that performed flawlessly. Your implementation technology can have different forms of scaling and features available in the progress bar, but the basic way of thinking about the problem is the same.

And yes, it did not really matter that the heuristic reference numbers were worked out on my machine - the only real problem is if you want to change the numbers when running on a different machine. But you still know the ratio (which is the only really important thing here), so you can see how your local hardware runs differently from the one I had.

Now the average SO reader may wonder why on earth someone would spend a week making a smooth progress bar. The feature was requested by the head salesman, and I believe he used it in sales meetings to get contracts. Money talks ;)

Answer (score 2):

In situations with threads or asynchronous processes/tasks like this, I find it helpful to have an abstract type or object in the main thread that represents (and ideally encapsulates) each process. So, for each worker thread, there will presumably be an object (let's call it `Operation`) in the main thread to manage that worker, and obviously there will be some kind of list-like data structure to hold these Operations.

Where applicable, each Operation provides the start/stop methods for its worker, and in some cases - such as yours - numeric properties representing the progress and expected total time or work of that particular Operation's task. The units don't necessarily need to be time-based, if you know you'll be performing 6,230 calculations, you can just think of these properties as calculation counts. Furthermore, each task will need to have some way of updating its owning Operation of its current progress in whatever mechanism is appropriate (callbacks, closures, event dispatching, or whatever mechanism your programming language/threading framework provides).

So while your actual work is being performed off in separate threads, a corresponding Operation object in the "main" thread is continually being updated/notified of its worker's progress. The progress bar can update itself accordingly, mapping the total of the Operations' "expected" times to its total, and the total of the Operations' "progress" times to its current progress, in whatever way makes sense for your progress bar framework.

Obviously there's a ton of other considerations/work that needs be done in actually implementing this, but I hope this gives you the gist of it.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple progress bars aren't such a bad idea, mind you. Or maybe a complex progress bar that shows several threads running (like download manager programs sometimes have). As long as the UI is intuitive, your users will appreciate the extra data.

When I try to answer such design questions I first try to look at similar or analogous problems in other application, and how they're solved. So I would suggest you do some research by considering other applications that display complex progress (like the download manager example) and try to adapt an existing solution to your application.

Sorry I can't offer more specific design, this is just general advice. :)

Answer (score 1):

Stick with Observer/Observable for this kind of thing.  Some object observes the various series processing threads and reports status by updating the summary bar.